# What is a martingale measure? And in particular what is a $L^2(P)$ valued sigma-finite measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

My text book defines a Martingale measure in the following way:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_t\}_{t \ge 0}, P)$ be a filtered probability space. A Processes $\{M_t(A)\}_{t \ge 0, \; A\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n) }$ is a martingale measure with respect to the filtration $\{\mathscr F_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ if:
>
> 1: $M_0(A)=0$ for any $A \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$
>
> 2: If $t\ge 0 $ then $M_t$ is a sigma finite $L^2(P)$ valued signed measure
>
> 3: For all $A \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$, $\{M_t(A)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a $0$-mean martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathscr F$.

I have a question about the meaning of (2). How should I think of this? For fixed $t \ge 0$, is $M_t(A)$ the measure of $A$ for any $A \in \mathscr B( \mathbb R^n)$? Or is $E\big[\big(M_t(A)\big)^2\big]$ the measure of $A$?

Also what woud it mean to be a sigma finite $L^2(P)$ valued measure? Does that mean that we can find a collection of countable sets, $\{B_n\}$, such that these sets cover $\mathbb R^n$ and that $E\big[\big(M_t(B_n)\big)^2\big] < \infty $?

Comment: what textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Its from the [mini course on spde](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cmlr/Preprints/Utah-Summer-School.pdf) but i found a better explanation from the [walsh notes](https://www.isibang.ac.in/~athreya/archive/spde/Walsh.pdf)

Comment: I see  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) just means that the countable additivity holds in $L^2(\Omega)$ instead of almost surely, so for disjoint $A_n$'s in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ you have \begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} E\left[ \left( M_t\left(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right) - \sum_{k=1}^n M_t(A_k)\right)^2 \right] = 0 \tag{*}\label{*}
\end{align}
for each $t \geq 0$.

I think you need an additional assumption of $$ A\cap B = \emptyset \implies M_t(A)\text{ and }M_t(B)\text{ are independent, for each } t\ge 0 $$ to get countable additivity (from \eqref{*}) under disjoint union for $E(M_t(\cdot)^2)$.

The assumption $$ M_t(\emptyset) = 0 \text{ a.s. for each } t\ge 0$$ will ensure that $E(M_t(\emptyset)^2) =0$. From these two assumptions together one can conclude that $E(M_t(\cdot)^2)$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[Note that the second assumption is also responsible for finite a.s. additivity of each $M_t$, again from \eqref{*}.]

Or, you can just demand that $E(M_t(A)^2)$ be a measure of $A$; see chapter 4 of Applebaum's book *Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus* for this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just checked out the book you recommended and it cleared up my questions. So when $M_t$ is a martingale measure then for each $t$ there exists a $\sigma$-finite measure $\rho_t$ such that $E\big[(M_t(A))^2\big]=\rho_t(A)$

Comment: I have one more question, In $\textit{Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus}$ on page 91 on $\textbf{Example 4.1.2}$ is there a typo? Should (1) say that those sets $A$ and $B$ be disjoint in $\Sigma \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^+)$ in order for $W(A)$ and $W(B)$ to be independent?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)\otimes \mathcal{F}$ is a typo and should be replaced with $\Sigma \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)$

Comment: In that example on pg 192, it claims that $W_t$ is $\textit{clearly}$ a martingale measure. I see how $W_t(\cdot)$ is finitely additive, namely for disjoint $\{A_i\}_{1 \le i \le n}$ in $\Sigma$ we have that since $W_t(A_i) \perp W_t(A_j)$ and because $E(W_t(A_i))=0$ then $$ E\big[\big(W_t(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)\big)^2  \big] =  E\big[\big(\sum_{i=1}^n W_t( A_i)\big)^2  \big] = \sum_{i=1}^n E\big[(W_t(A_i))^2  \big] $$ but why does this hold if we consider $\{A_i\}_{i \ge 1}$ to be disjoint?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking why the condition of pairwise disjoint-ness is necessary for the above calculation to go through?

Comment: If we want to show that $W_t$ is a martingale measure then dont we need to show that $\rho(t,A) := E\big[(W_t(A))^2\big]$ is a measure? So we need to show that is is countably additive. I was saying in my previous comment that I see why we have finite additivity but not countable additivity. I can make a new question and post the link for it here if you would rather answer that in there?

Comment: Perhaps some clarifications are in order: The definition of martingale measure that you gave in your question is *not* the same as the one in Applebaum -- we are talking about two related but slightly different objects. In Applebaum's definition, we are *demanding* that $E(M_t(A)^2) = \rho(t,A)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure; so if you have a martingale measure according to this definition, the countable additivity of $E(M_t(A)^2) $ is *already given*.

Comment: On the other hand, the definition in your question never demands that $E(M_t(A)^2)$ be countably additive under disjoint union. So if you want to prove that an object is a martingale measure according to your definition, you don't need countable additivity.

Comment: In you answer to my original post, you said that (2) just meant that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} E\left[ \left( M_t\left(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right) - \sum_{k=1}^n M_t(A_k)\right)^2 \right] = 0 $$ and doesnt this mean that $E\big[(M_t(A))^2\big]$ is countably additive? Ie: $E\big[(M_t(\cup_iA_i))^2\big]=\sum_iE\big[(M_t(Ai))^2\big]$

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't see any way of proving $E[(M_t(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k))^2] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[M_t(A_k)^2]$ from the limit statement without using the two assumptions that I stated in my answer.

Comment: Isn't it from reverse triangle inequality? Let $||X|| := E(X^2)$ which defines a norm and let $f_n := \sum_{k=1}^n M_t(A_k)$ and $f:=M_t(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)$. Then the limit statemeant means that $||f-f_n||\to0$ and reverse trangle inequality gives us $||f_n|| \to ||f||$. And $$||f_n||=E\big[(\sum_{i=1}^nM(A_i))^2\big]=\sum_{i=1}^nE\big[(M_t(A_i))^2\big]\to \sum_{i=1}^\infty E\big[(M_t(A_i))^2\big]$$ where I used that $M_t(A)$ has $0$-mean and $M_t(A_i)\perp M_t(A_j)$

Comment: Ok, so we don't need $M_t(\emptyset) =0$ (and, in particular, a.s. finite additivity of $M_t$) to prove countable additivity of $E(M_t(\cdot)^2)$. Only the independence assumption is enough. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Sorry but about $\textbf{Example 4.1.2}$ on page 192, Why is $W_t$ $\textit{clearly}$ a martingale measure according to Applebaum's definition? In particular, why does there exist a measure $\rho(t,A) = E\big[(W_t(A)^2\big]$? Because of independence and the $0$-mean property of $W_t$ I already proved that $\rho(t,A)$ was finitely additive but in order to show its a measure it needs to be countably additive.

Comment: Im pretty sure I figured it out. $\rho(t,A) = E\big[(W_t(A)^2\big]$ is precisely $t\mu(A)$ by definition of white noise  where $\mu$ is the measure given on the space $(S,\Sigma)$. So trivially, $\rho(t,A)=E\big[(W_t(A)^2\big]=t\mu (A)$ and hence $E\big[(W_t(A)^2\big]$ is a measure.